# Is there an online tool for visual drawing of contours on canvas and grabbing the prepared code?

Tags: html, canvas, code-generation, wysiwyg

While a concept of quadratic and bézier curves is quite simple, visual drawing is much more simpler. I wonder if there's an online tool for drawing paths visually and then just grabbing the code? For example recently I've stumbled upon this one: [Canvas Bézier Curve Example](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/canvas-curves/bezier-curve.html), pretty cool, but as it states - it's just an example, not a tool.

Maybe there is more versatile thing on the web somewhere (there should be), based on same concepts?

Answer (score 1):

I think your best shot would be draw using SVG vector art software like Inkscape, then export this SVG file. Modern browsers can read SVG and paint it on the canvas.

SVG is open, XML, based format and quite human readable.

Answer (score 1):

There are many great tools such as Inkscape that will output SVG paths.

Then there are many SVG-to-canvas libraries ([here's one](http://ajaxian.com/archives/canvg-using-canvas-to-render-svg-files)) that you can use to turn the resulting SVG into canvas paths.

Of course its worth asking yourself if you can just use SVG and save yourself the trouble of one step!